# XPath:: Alternative ways to get a desired element

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find all possible (better) combinations to get the last/first select-able element in the following HTML Structure.

```
<div class="mx-datepicker-body"><div class="mx-calendar mx-calendar-panel-date"><div class="mx-calendar-header"><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-double-left"><i class="mx-icon-double-left"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-left"><i class="mx-icon-left"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-double-right"><i class="mx-icon-double-right"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-right"><i class="mx-icon-right"></i></button> <span class="mx-calendar-header-label"><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-current-month">
      Jun
    </button><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-current-year">
      2020
    </button></span></div> <div class="mx-calendar-content"><table class="mx-table mx-table-year" style="display: none;"><tr><td data-year="2020" class="cell active"><div>2020</div></td><td data-year="2021" class="cell"><div>2021</div></td></tr><tr><td data-year="2022" class="cell"><div>2022</div></td><td data-year="2023" class="cell"><div>2023</div></td></tr><tr><td data-year="2024" class="cell"><div>2024</div></td><td data-year="2025" class="cell"><div>2025</div></td></tr><tr><td data-year="2026" class="cell"><div>2026</div></td><td data-year="2027" class="cell"><div>2027</div></td></tr><tr><td data-year="2028" class="cell"><div>2028</div></td><td data-year="2029" class="cell"><div>2029</div></td></tr></table> <table class="mx-table mx-table-month" style="display: none;"><tr><td data-month="0" class="cell"><div>Jan</div></td><td data-month="1" class="cell"><div>Feb</div></td><td data-month="2" class="cell"><div>Mar</div></td></tr><tr><td data-month="3" class="cell"><div>Apr</div></td><td data-month="4" class="cell"><div>May</div></td><td data-month="5" class="cell active"><div>Jun</div></td></tr><tr><td data-month="6" class="cell"><div>Jul</div></td><td data-month="7" class="cell"><div>Aug</div></td><td data-month="8" class="cell"><div>Sep</div></td></tr><tr><td data-month="9" class="cell"><div>Oct</div></td><td data-month="10" class="cell"><div>Nov</div></td><td data-month="11" class="cell"><div>Dec</div></td></tr></table> <table class="mx-table mx-table-date"><thead><tr><!----> <th>Mo</th><th>Tu</th><th>We</th><th>Th</th><th>Fr</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="-6" title="2020-05-25" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>25</div></td><td data-day="-5" title="2020-05-26" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>26</div></td><td data-day="-4" title="2020-05-27" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>27</div></td><td data-day="-3" title="2020-05-28" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>28</div></td><td data-day="-2" title="2020-05-29" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>29</div></td><td data-day="-1" title="2020-05-30" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>30</div></td><td data-day="0" title="2020-05-31" class="cell not-current-month disabled"><div>31</div></td></tr><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="1" title="2020-06-01" class="cell disabled"><div>1</div></td><td data-day="2" title="2020-06-02" class="cell disabled"><div>2</div></td><td data-day="3" title="2020-06-03" class="cell disabled"><div>3</div></td><td data-day="4" title="2020-06-04" class="cell today"><div>4</div></td><td data-day="5" title="2020-06-05" class="cell"><div>5</div></td><td data-day="6" title="2020-06-06" class="cell"><div>6</div></td><td data-day="7" title="2020-06-07" class="cell"><div>7</div></td></tr><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="8" title="2020-06-08" class="cell"><div>8</div></td><td data-day="9" title="2020-06-09" class="cell"><div>9</div></td><td data-day="10" title="2020-06-10" class="cell"><div>10</div></td><td data-day="11" title="2020-06-11" class="cell"><div>11</div></td><td data-day="12" title="2020-06-12" class="cell"><div>12</div></td><td data-day="13" title="2020-06-13" class="cell"><div>13</div></td><td data-day="14" title="2020-06-14" class="cell"><div>14</div></td></tr><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="15" title="2020-06-15" class="cell"><div>15</div></td><td data-day="16" title="2020-06-16" class="cell"><div>16</div></td><td data-day="17" title="2020-06-17" class="cell"><div>17</div></td><td data-day="18" title="2020-06-18" class="cell"><div>18</div></td><td data-day="19" title="2020-06-19" class="cell"><div>19</div></td><td data-day="20" title="2020-06-20" class="cell"><div>20</div></td><td data-day="21" title="2020-06-21" class="cell"><div>21</div></td></tr><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="22" title="2020-06-22" class="cell"><div>22</div></td><td data-day="23" title="2020-06-23" class="cell"><div>23</div></td><td data-day="24" title="2020-06-24" class="cell"><div>24</div></td><td data-day="25" title="2020-06-25" class="cell"><div>25</div></td><td data-day="26" title="2020-06-26" class="cell"><div>26</div></td><td data-day="27" title="2020-06-27" class="cell"><div>27</div></td><td data-day="28" title="2020-06-28" class="cell"><div>28</div></td></tr><tr class="mx-date-row"><!----> <td data-day="29" title="2020-06-29" class="cell"><div>29</div></td><td data-day="30" title="2020-06-30" class="cell"><div>30</div></td><td data-day="31" title="2020-07-01" class="cell not-current-month"><div>1</div></td><td data-day="32" title="2020-07-02" class="cell not-current-month"><div>2</div></td><td data-day="33" title="2020-07-03" class="cell not-current-month"><div>3</div></td><td data-day="34" title="2020-07-04" class="cell not-current-month"><div>4</div></td><td data-day="35" title="2020-07-05" class="cell not-current-month"><div>5</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

Here is the image representation:

[image]

In this, the first selectable element is **Day 1** and last selectable element is **Day 29**. So, I have the followings xpaths which are working perfectly fine for Day29 and I am just wondering what other ways around to achieve the same.

> `(//td[@class='cell' and @data-day])[last()]` and `//td[@class='cell today']`

Comment: What do you mean by "other ways around to achieve the same"?

Comment: A solution can be derived by many ways., given 2 xpaths are 2 ways and would like to know all possible solutions (xpath) to identify day1 & day29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second XPath needs to be fixed since it returns the node `data-day= 30`.

```
//td[@class='cell'][last()][following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'disabled')]]
```

As alternatives (`data-day=29`) :

```
//td[contains(@class,"disabled")][1]/preceding-sibling::td[1]

//td[@class='cell'][following::td[1][contains(@class,'disabled')]]
```

For `data-day=1` :

```
(//td[@class="cell"])[1]
(//td[.="1"])[1]
//td[@class="cell not-current-month"][last()]/following::td[1]
```

To get the two with one XPath :

```
(//td[@class="cell"])[position()=1 or position()=last()]
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately none of them works for the same html structure. I've included the intended xpath in my original question.

Comment: I don't understand. XPath provided are perfectly fine and select what you need. What do you mean by "the same html structure "? I've added the XPath in order to select the first day. Regarding the XPath you've provided `//td[@class='cell not-current-month']/../td[@class='cell'][last()]`, it selects the 5th July node. I suppose that's an error ?

Comment: It seems the DOM has been modified and I see., the best way to achieve those are  `(//td[@class='cell' and @data-day])[last()]` and `//td[@class='cell today']`. Anyway, thank you for your effort.